# Java Force Variable to have specific values

Tags: java, variables

I want to force one variable to have specific values. For example lets talk about CPU. Lets say that we have the following

```
public class CPU
{
   static String CPU_TYPE;
   static String CPU_SPEED;

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      CPU_TYPE = "Don't allow this";
   }
}
```

I want for example the CPU_TYPE to be only AMD/Intel and CPU_SPEED To be only 3.0 or 4.0.
I tried with enum but i am doing something wrong and its not working.

I don't want a simple solution with if statements since i have load of these variables and specific values.

Thank you

Comment: enum is the right way to go.  Why don't you show us what you tried?

Comment: What was the problem when using the enums?

Answer (score 4):

**Do use enums** in this case, simply use [Enum.valueOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) to parse your incoming string. It will throw an IllegalArgumentException when it can't convert it to one of the existing enum values.

Answer (score 1):

As @ChristopheD said, use Enums.  Here's an example:

```
    package main;

public enum CPU_TYPE {

    TYPE1,
    TYPE2,
    TYPE3;

}
```

and then in your main class:

```
public CPU_TYPE cpuType = new CPU_TYPE();

public static void main(String[] args) {
//setting

cpuType = CPU_TYPE.TYPE1;

// getting
if(cpuType == CPU_TYPE.TYPE1) {
cpuType = CPU_TYPE.TYPE2;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

​Java has a built solution for this kind of problems, it is called `enum`. There is no other way to restrict a variable do some pre-defined values without checking manually in your code.